# I get "gcc.exe: fatal error: cannot execute 'cc1plus'" when I try to compile a program in C++ in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, compiler-errors, c++14, mingw-w64

I get the error "gcc.exe: fatal error: cannot execute 'cc1plus'" when I want to compile any program in C++. I didn't installed the compiler Mingw-w64, downloaded the zip from *winlibs.com* and I copied it to "C:". Then I added to the environment variable *Path*.

I tried to move the library *cc1plus.exe.o* to the *lib* folder of Mingw, and used the commands *gcc test.cpp -o test.exe* and *gcc.exe test.cpp -o text.exe*.

The OS is Windows.

Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't c++ programs be compiled with `g++`?

Comment: Go to [the official MinGW-64 site](https://www.mingw-w64.org) instead, and [download](https://www.mingw-w64.org/downloads/) an actual installer instead.

Comment: instead of mucking about with files who's purpose you don't understand, just download and instal everything from a reputable site  such as nuwen.net

Comment: gcc will compile files with the .cpp extension correctly, but it won't invoke the linker properly

Comment: I went to official MinGW-64 and there they put the domain WinLibs.com for download the zip with mingw. In other OS i had compiled with gcc and it worked. Anyways, i tried with g++ too.

Comment: do what i said - go to nuwen.net and download and install from there there are clear instructions. stl, the author of the site. is a principal dev working on ms implementation of the standard lib and knows what he is about